# Pandas datetime index cumulative week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with datetimeindex.

```
>>> df.head() 
Out[6]: 
                                1
2004-01-02 09:00:00+11:00  0.7519
2004-01-02 10:00:00+11:00  0.7520
2004-01-02 12:00:00+11:00  0.7515
2004-01-02 13:00:00+11:00  0.7502
2004-01-02 14:00:00+11:00  0.7519
```

I want to keep track of weeks count. I don't know upfront if some days might be missing so can't simply divide entry number by 7.

If I do the following, I get the weeks within a year:

```
df['temp']= df.index.week
df[df.index.year==2005].head()
Out[20]: 
                                1  temp
2005-01-03 10:00:00+11:00  0.7829     1
2005-01-03 11:00:00+11:00  0.7815     1
2005-01-03 12:00:00+11:00  0.7814     1
2005-01-03 13:00:00+11:00  0.7797     1
2005-01-03 14:00:00+11:00  0.7731     1
```

The problem with this is that weeks end at 52 and start again at 1 for the next year. I thought I could group by year and week number to get cumulative week count but the same week could fall into 2 yrs e.g.

```
>>> df[df.index.year==2008].resample('d').tail()
Out[30]: 
                                  1  temp

2008-12-27 00:00:00+11:00  0.683678    52
2008-12-28 00:00:00+11:00       NaN   NaN
2008-12-29 00:00:00+11:00  0.689414     1
2008-12-30 00:00:00+11:00  0.690654     1
2008-12-31 00:00:00+11:00  0.691058     1

>>> df[df.index.year==2009].resample('d').head()
Out[29]: 
                                  1  temp
2009-01-01 00:00:00+11:00  0.695833     1
2009-01-02 00:00:00+11:00  0.697680     1
2009-01-03 00:00:00+11:00  0.705733     1
2009-01-04 00:00:00+11:00       NaN   NaN
2009-01-05 00:00:00+11:00  0.711436     2
```

Is there a way to keep track of cumulative weeks?

Answer (score 1):

The reason Ken Wei's solution is incomplete is that weeks that starts previous year, but are majority of them happens the next year, pandas attributes as firsts, what you can see in the example below:

```
              weekIndex  weekNum
<DTYYYYMMDD>                    
2001-12-28       200152       52
2001-12-31       200101        1
2002-01-02       200201        1
2002-01-03       200201        1
```

As you can see, one week has been duplicated.

As the solution, I suggest using loops that create list, which is easily convertable to pandas DataFrame:

```
df['weekNum'] = df.index.week

last_x = 0
numerator = 0
cumWeek = list()

for x in df['weekNum']:
    if x != last_x:
        numerator += 1
        cumWeek.append(numerator)
    else:
        cumWeek.append(numerator)
    last_x = x

cumWeek = pd.DataFrame(cumWeek, columns=['cumWeek'], index=df.index)
df = pd.concat([df, cumWeek], axis=1)
```

cumWeek stores desired output alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use both week and year:

```
df['week_no'] = df.index.week + (df.index.year - df.index.year.min()) * 52
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to give?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible solution, may not be very good. Any improvements are welcome.

```
df['temp']= df.index.week
df.loc[(df.temp == 1) & (df.index.month == 12), 'temp'] = 53
df.loc[(df.temp == 52) & (df.index.month == 1), 'temp'] = 0
df['cum_wk'] = df.temp + (df.index.year - df.index.year.min()) * 52
```