# Cumulative week number for subsequent years in data

Tags: python, pandas, week-number

I would like to add week number to a Pandas DataFrame. But it should be a cumulative week count that continues after 1-52 in the next year with 53-104 (instead of simply starting over again from 1-52). This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192568/pandas-datetime-index-cumulative-week) is treating a similar question but is not giving the desired outcome since it provides a rank instead of week number.

As an example, I use the following dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2018-01-03', '2018-01-10', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-02', '2019-03-15', '2019-12-31', '2020-01-02']})
```

Then I extracted `week` and `year` from the data.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().year
```

And found the following solution that works.

```
df['Weeknr'] = df['Week'] + df['Year'].map({2018:0, 2019:52, 2020:104})
```

But I am curious if something better exists, where for ex. it is not necessary to put in manually the years 2018, 2019 and 2020 in the code (since years can change for new data):

So the question is, is there any function or any other way the cumulative week can be computed?

[image]

Comment: why do you need this computation? I had not seen it requested before, could your use case be solved by an index with `Year, Week` ?

Comment: In the first place because I'd like to have a plot x-axis that continues beyond week 52. Indeed Year, Week index may work as well but I was curious if there is a way to display cumulative weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do:

```
df['weeknr'] = df['Week'] + (df['Year'] - df['Year'].min())*52
```

Output:

```
        Date  Week  Year  weeknr
0 2018-01-03     1  2018       1
1 2018-01-10     2  2018       2
2 2018-12-31     1  2019      53
3 2019-01-06     1  2019      53
4 2019-01-02     1  2019      53
5 2019-03-15    11  2019      63
6 2019-12-31     1  2020     105
7 2020-01-02     1  2020     105
```

---

**Update**: An idea on the absolute week number instead of the isocalendar's:

```
min_year = pd.to_datetime(f"{df['Date'].dt.year.min()}-01")
df['weeknr'] = (df['Date'] - min_year) // pd.to_timedelta('7D') + 1
```

This would tive the same `weeknr` as the previous method for the sample data.

Comment: what would you do with 53-week years?

Comment: Technically, all years stretch over 53 weeks. I would just evaluate weeks as `day_offsets // 7`. But that's not what OP's asking for :p.

Comment: It is a clever answer and I upvoted, but even though it is not explicit that it should consider 53-week years, there is one every 5-6 years, and it does say that the years in the data might change... so I would not be a bad idea to generalize the solution

Comment: @Quang Hoang: you mean by `day_offsets` 366 days for leap years, else 365 days?

Comment: Yes, otherwise week number will be shifted every 4-6 years like @RichieV mentioned.

Comment: @QuangHoang: thank you! Does this take into account a leap year?

Comment: Yes, because it only calculate the day differences and then floor divide by 7.